# Trying to write a tkinter popup with dynamic text and confirmation button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a popup for messages such as "Action completed" and I want a button on it to close the popup (A simple OK which quits only the popup). It also sometimes moves behind the window which is annoying. I have some code for the button but it has an issue with the geometry of the shape since the shape isn't exactly defined as it is variable through the size of font and text length.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import pygame
import sys

def Text(Text_input, Font, Background, Foreground):
    my_window = tk.Tk()
    my_window.title(Text_input)
    my_window.geometry()
    help_label = tk.Label(my_window, font = Font, bg=Background, fg=Foreground, text = Text_input)
    help_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    button = tk.Button(my_window, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=quit)
    button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
    my_window.mainloop()

Text("Hello", "calibri 80", "white", "black")
```

Comment: You can't use both `.pack` and `.grid` in the same window so change `help_label.grid()` to `help_label.pack()`. Also the `my_window.geometry()` is useless.

Comment: If you want to close the popup and not python, use `command=my_window.destroy` instead of `command=quit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own experience wanting to achieve this, I wrote a simple tkinter code `export_success.py` as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('280x100')
root.title("Export Status")
root.config(bg="")
style = ttk.Style()


label_0 = Label(root, text="Export Successful", width=20, background="white", foreground="grey15", font=("Arial, bold", 15)).place(x=50, y=23)

exit1 = Button(root, text='Exit', style='C.TButton', width=11, command=root.destroy).place(x=100, y=60)

root.mainloop()
```

I then just insert this code `os.system('python export_success.py')` at the end of my tkinker window that I'm working on.

In this case I'm exporting my information and wanted to know when it is successful.

I am not saying this is best practice and there might be other ways, I just found it to work out for me.

Comment: Why are you using `os.system('python export_success.py')`, when just using `import export_success` will do the same thing?

Comment: @TheLizzard I found that when I use `import export_success` at the beginning or end it runs with the code and pops-up at a random time. I wanted it to run specifically after the export is done. This way, from my point of view, it will only run that pop-up upon successfully running all other code in question. Like I said, it might not be best practice, but it works every time. Even better and more accurate would be the entire file path, but I shortened it for readability.

Comment: Use `import export_success` in the same place you would use `os.system('python export_success.py')`. The only time it wouldn't work is if it is in a `lambda`. Also you should really try using best practices

Comment: @TheLizzard My main issue with this specific query i had was that it had to be implemented on many different scripts. I cannot deny that the `import` option was my first idea to implement, but If i replace the `os.system` line with `import` then the file does not run after the export is done. It just pops-up immediately. I also had the issue of the pop-up not being on top of the current window using `import` which is another issue stated in your question above.

Comment: I haven't compiled any of my python programs. Also about the issue of it not being on the top, there is a method for that: `<tkinter.Tk>.lift()`

Comment: @TheLizzard I completely agree that my above method would not be recommended by all devs. I just had an issue similar to the question above, where I came up with a solution based on my current knowledge (All-though quite limited in the grand scheme) I just felt that is was easier to read and edit upon request.